# Compare two dictionaries by key and create a new one where keys don’t match

Tags: c#

I have two dictionaries of type (string, string). I need to compare these and create a new dictionary where just the Keys don’t match. For example, given these values

```
Dictionary A

Key  Value
=========
A      B
C      D


Dictionary B

Key  Value
=========
A      Z
E      D
```

I need to create a new dictionary that would just have a single entry of (E,D)

==== Edit ====

When the compare is done I am just involving the keys, the values are of no interest. The key values are just strings so don't link to other objects. There is no hidden mapping etc. The "Value" only comes into play when I have the resulting dictionary as this is then used in my program. Think of this problem as if the values didn't exist and I was just trying to get a list of keys that are in dictionary "B" but not in "dictionary "A". I am not interested in key "C" as I am just interested in the unique keys that are just in dictionary "B" but not in dictionary "A".

Comment: What happens to (C,D) in this scenario? In other words, do you only want entries from Dictionary B whose keys do not match entries in Dictionary A?

Comment: Can we assume that a value is not mapped from different keys in the same dictionary? That is, that we can not have for instance `(A=>B)` and `(C=>B)` in the same dictionary?

Comment: this question is not precis enough to give a proper answer.

Comment: @DanJ, Yes, I only want entries from dictionary "B" who's keys do not appear in dictionary "A"

Comment: @Jocke, I have added more information to my question. Hope it is now clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create a dictionary containing all elements of `B`, whose keys are not in `A`:

```
var C = B.Where(x => !A.ContainsKey(x.Key))
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

In case you want to create a dictionary containing all elements of `B`, whose values are in `A`, but whose keys do not match those of the corresponding values of `A`, you can use this:

```
var C = 
    (from a in A
     join b in B on a.Value equals b.Value
     where a.Key != b.Key
     select b)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Note however, this will fail if `A` contains the same value with two or more keys, e.g. `(A, B)`, `(C, D)`, and `(F, D)`. To address that you can do something like this:

```
var C = 
    (from a in A
     group a by a.Value into g
     let a = g.First()
     join b in B on a.Value equals b.Value
     where a.Key != b.Key
     select b)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: This does not look right: I think the OP wants (E,D) because `D` is in dictionary A under a different key.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not sure about that. `D` is one of values, but OP states "*create a new dictionary where just the Keys don’t match*".

Comment: That's exactly the part that makes me think that he wants pairs where the keys do not match, but the values do match (see Dan J's comment).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I suppose that may be what OP is looking for. I've provided a solution that should work in that case as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess my original question wasn’t too clear but you interpreted it correctly and have given multiple solutions. Also thanks to Tim Schmelter who also gave great answers.

Answer (score 8):

So you only want to add entries that exist in the second dictionary which are not in the first and not vice-versa?

```
var dictC = dictB.Keys.Except(dictA.Keys)
    .ToDictionary(bKey => bKey, bKey => dictB[bKey]);
```

If you also want the opposite you could use this approach using `Concat` on an anonymous type:

```
var dictC = dictB.Keys.Except(dictA.Keys)
    .Select(bKey => new{ Key=bKey, Value=dictB[bKey] })
    .Concat(dictA.Keys.Except(dictB.Keys)
    .Select(aKey => new{ Key=aKey, Value=dictA[aKey] }))
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Duplicate keys aren't possible here since the first query looks for keys in dictionary-1 which are not in the other whereas the second query looks for the opposite. So it's safe to use `Concat` and `ToDictionary`.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, too. I'm curious which solution would be faster.

Comment: This does not look right: I think the OP wants (E,D) because `D` is in dictionary A under a different key.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hmm, maybe. But what happens with duplicate values where one has a matching key and the other(s) not? The question is not that clear.

Comment: I cannot say until OP replies to Dan J's comment :-(

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you so much Tim. Your solution works great for me. You save me:) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want key-value pairs from dictionary `B` where dictionary `A` has a different key for that value. In that case, I'd do something like this:

```
// sample data
Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
a.Add("A", "B"); a.Add("C", "D");
Dictionary<string, string> b = new Dictionary<string, string>();
b.Add("A", "Z"); b.Add("E", "D");

// first, reverse dictionary A for simplicity
// to quickly get the key for a value
var revA = a.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Value, kv => kv.Key);

// and then compute the result
var result = b.Where(kv => revA.ContainsKey(kv.Value) && revA[kv.Value] != kv.Key)
              .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

This of course assumes that we can not have a value mapped from different keys in the same dictionary. That is, that we can not have for instance `(A=>B)` and `(C=>B)` in the same dictionary. I think this is implicitly true in your question.